# Use external CSS in `cshtml` with RazorEngine

Tags: css, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razorengine

I wanted to use external & internal CSS in my **cshtml** file.

I'm using here [RazorEngine](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/) compiler.

If I try to run without adding external CSS, it is working fine. But when I try to add an external CSS, it is throwing an error mentioned below:

> RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: 'Errors while
>   compiling a Template. Please try the following to solve the situation:
>   * If the problem is about missing/invalid references or multiple defines either try to load 
>       the missing references manually (in the compiling appdomain!) or
>       Specify your references manually by providing your own IReferenceResolver implementation.
>       See https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ReferenceResolver.html for details.
>       Currently all references have to be available as files!   * If you get 'class' does not contain a definition for 'member': 
>           try another modelType (for example 'null' to make the model dynamic).
>           NOTE: You CANNOT use typeof(dynamic) to make the model dynamic!
>       Or try to use static instead of anonymous/dynamic types. More details about the error:
>    - error: (17, 29) The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context Temporary files of the compilation can be found in (please
>   delete the folder):
>   C:\Users\pratik.soni\AppData\Local\Temp\RazorEngine_d253hedw.3b5 The
>   template we tried to compile is: 
>   ------------- START ----------- @model DRC.DTO.EFiling.NewEFilingDeclarationModel;

CSHTML file is as below:

```
@model DRC.DTO.EFiling.NewEFilingDeclarationModel;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/wwwroot/CSS/StyleSheet.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body class="bg-gray">
    <h2 class="h2">VAT e-Filing</h2>
    <div class="bg-white">
        <div class="">
```

.
.
.

Code for compiling template is as below:

```
public string CompileTemplate(string templatePath, string name, object model)
        {
            string rootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
            string fullPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, templatePath, name).ToString();
            string templateSource = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);

            string templateString;
            if (Engine.Razor.IsTemplateCached(name, model.GetType()))
            {
                templateString = Engine.Razor.Run(name, model.GetType(), model);
            }
            else
            {
                templateString = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(templateSource, name, model.GetType(), model); //**GETTING ERROR ON THIS LINE**
            }

            return templateString;
        }
```

**Stylesheet.css**

```
body {
}

.h2 {
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`UrlHelper` only exists within the context of a request. You're rendering the view outside the request pipeline, so `Url` is not defined. However, you don't really need it here anyways; you should be able to just change your code to:

```
<link href="~/wwwroot/CSS/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is resolving the issue. But unfortunately, it is not applying the external CSS to the PDF.

Comment: When generating a PDF, external links aren't going to really work. It depends a lot on the library you're using, but generally there's a provided method for including external CSS, rather than referencing it in the document itself.